# Get all date based on given requirement

Tags: node.js, momentjs

My requirement.EX: date(2019-07-01) in that month 4th week i wanna particular dates based on like["1","6","7"] . ex Result like: [2019-07-28,2019-,2019-08-02,2019-08-03]

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what input you are getting and what is the expected output? It's a bit confusing from the text

Comment: Hi CapeAndCow: like I am given 2019-07-1 in that 4th week all date push to an Array. I am given particular date and week and days like :
"days": ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"],
            "week": ["4"],
like result [2019-07-28,2019-07-29,2019-07-30,2019-07-31,2019-08-01,2019-08-02,2019-08-03]. this was  i want...

Comment: @koteswararaopv I don't understand how `2019-07-1` translates to a 4th week. Are you saying that, given any date, find the week number based on the month from that date? However, it seems that you don't want the week number from your example, rather, you want 7 days beginning from the first Sunday in that block? It is hard to determine what your requirements are from only these examples.

Comment: Hi caladeve.thanks for responding. yeah what i am saying. in that month 4th week i wanna particular dates based on like["1","6","7"] . ex Result like:
[2019-07-28,2019-,2019-08-02,2019-08-03]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = {"2020-07-01",
```

"2020-07-02",
"2020-07-03",
"2020-07-04",
"2020-07-05",
"2020-07-06",
"2020-07-07",
"2020-07-08",
"2020-07-09",
"2020-07-10",
"2020-07-11",
"2020-07-12",
"2020-07-13",
"2020-07-14",
"2020-07-15",
"2020-07-16",
"2020-07-17",
"2020-07-18",
"2020-07-19",
"2020-07-20",
"2020-07-21",
"2020-07-22",
"2020-07-23",
"2020-07-24",
"2020-07-25",
"2020-07-26",
"2020-07-27",
"2020-07-28",
"2020-07-29",
"2020-07-30",
"2020-07-31",}

```
for(var n = 0; n < data.on.order.length; n++){
for(var m = 0; m < data.on.days.length; m++){
    //****
if(data.on.order[n] === '1'){
 firstdayMonth = moment(endOfMonth).date(0);
}else{
 firstdayMonth = moment(endOfMonth).date(1);
}
// console.log('------------1',firstdayMonth)
var firstdayWeek = moment(firstdayMonth).isoWeekday(parseInt(data.on.days[m],10));
console.log('------------2 ',firstdayWeek)
// if(data.on.order[n] === "1"){
nWeeks = parseInt(data.on.order[n],10);
// }else{
//  nWeeks = parseInt(data.on.order[n],10);
// }
var nextEvent = moment(firstdayWeek).add(nWeeks,'w');
// = moment(firstdayWeek).add(nWeeks,'w');
console.log('------------3',nextEvent,'---- ',nWeeks)
//****
if(nextEvent.isAfter(eventDate)){
eventDate = nextEvent;
// console.log("### eventDate: ", eventDate)
// console.log('Total dates in month ',eventDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
meetings.push(eventDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
}
}
}
```

Comment: OUTPUT : ["2020-07-01",
"2020-07-02",
"2020-07-03",
"2020-07-04",
"2020-07-05",
"2020-07-06",
"2020-07-07",
"2020-07-08",
"2020-07-09",
"2020-07-10",
"2020-07-11",
"2020-07-12",
"2020-07-13",
"2020-07-14",
"2020-07-15",
"2020-07-16",
"2020-07-17",
"2020-07-18",
"2020-07-19",
"2020-07-20",
"2020-07-21",
"2020-07-22",
"2020-07-23",
"2020-07-24",
"2020-07-25",
"2020-07-26",
"2020-07-27",
"2020-07-28",
"2020-07-29",
"2020-07-30",
"2020-07-31",]